# Why are simple insulators not used for radiation detection?

Tags: particle-detectors

Solid state detectors are based on semiconductors and in particular on silicon pn junctions.
When a pn junction is reverse polarized, a significat portion of the semiconductor is depleted of free charge carriers. Ionizing radiation that deposits energy within the depletion region generates a number of electron-hole pairs that drift under the electric field. During drift, these pairs induce a current on the polarizing electrodes, according to Ramo's theorem.
This current signal can me measured with a sufficient signal to noise ratio since only a very low current flows through a reverse biased pn junction.

Would it be possible to use simple a (good) insulator to perform the same task, but without introducing doping?

Comment: A [Spark chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark_chamber) is something like what you are asking for. But it uses a gas instead of a solid.

Comment: How about a liquid argon calorimeter? Liquid argon is a perfectly good insulator and has to be, otherwise the charges would neutralize before they can drift to the electrodes. One of the requirements for a good detector is drift velocity. Too fast and the charge will neutralize. Too slow and we don't get a high enough time resolution. The other one is that the atoms of the medium don't trap the electrons. That's why we use liquid argon and not liquid oxygen.

Comment: Thanks. Why a too fast drift velocity does cause charge neutralization?